# how to avoid the changing the date in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I would like to ask about how to code datetime in CONSOLE vb.net. I already got the format but my problem is after I inputted another data today to the database.

[image]

In this image,my data retrieval was error. The ID (1,2,3,4,5,6)should be jan 2. Unfortunately, the output was today after Ive put new data to the database. I was confused on how to code to avoid changing the date.

this is my code:

```
   Dim datetoday As DateTime = DateTime.Now
   Dim dateyesterday As DateTime = DateTime.Today
   Dim format As String = "yyyy d MMM"
   Sub Main()
    s = New Sessions
    ds = s.GetSession("select CLIENTID, SESSIONCOST from SESSIONS ORDER BY CLIENTID ASC")
    Dim startVal = 0
    Dim endVal = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count

    For var = startVal To endVal - 1
        Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables(0).Rows(var)("CLIENTID").ToString() + " " + ds.Tables(0).Rows(var)("SESSIONCOST").ToString() + " " + datetoday.ToString(format))  'code for display id and name
    Next
```

Im hoping for you feedback. A sample code would be enough to understand. Thank you

Comment: You should post your code to show us what you're doing, and highlight exactly where you're having problems

Comment: You need to go back to the FAQ's and learn how to use Stack Overflow. I'm not going to paste your code into an editor so that I can read it, and try to figure out what your problem is. Make a change to your original post, and ask a straightforward question citing lines in your code.

Comment: I looked at your profile and see that the SQL statements you have pasted here are a product of answers you got from other threads on SO. We are not here to do your work for you. Start with the basics. here is a link to MSDN's VB.net area: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh388568

Comment: @Origin : Im sorry. I was just asking for guidelines so that I can proceed to my program. Im just asking for a sample code so that I can analyze the code then put it in my program.

Answer (score 1):

Having the code in your original post is much better - but have you actually read what you've written?

```
Dim datetoday As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim dateyesterday As DateTime = DateTime.Today
```

These two are going to be pretty much the same thing. If you want yesterday, you would need to subtract a day from `Now`

```
Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables(0).Rows(var)("CLIENTID").ToString() + " " + ds.Tables(0).Rows(var)("SESSIONCOST").ToString() + " " + datetoday.ToString(format))  'code for display id and name
```

Also - it doesn't appear that you are retrieving (or even storing?) the date in your database. If you are simply printing out the result of DateTime.Now then the date printed next to each row will always be the current date, and not necessarily when the object was created.

Comment: It is not just printing out the result, my next thing to do is to insert it to mysql. That's why I should update the data. Regarding Dim dateyesterday was just a declaration. It was not use yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UTC dates (DateTime.UtcNow) in both your app and in your datastore.  Only format it with the timezone adjusted date when displaying to a user.